# What happens to a user’s session when I publish my C# MVC application from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, iis, caching

I have a C# MVC application, I publish it to an external hosting company, if I have say 10 users logged into the application what happens to their sessions?

I've noticed what will happen with me is I go to log into the application after a publish, it appears to log me in, however I use a client-side binding language called Knockout and so it then shows me the user interface, however it hasn't actually loaded the data back from the server. It looks like I'm logged in but if I hit F5 to refresh then I'm logged out, it’s like the session is cached or something but not properly.

I'm thinking of implementing some sort of JavaScript timer to ensure the application has access and running it every few seconds, if it cannot access the server then redirect to the login page.

Comment: so what I tried doing was using the publishing setting "delete all existing files prior to publish", this completely removes the app as you'd expect but I still get the same issue, I can log into an old session, I hit F5 am logged out and have to login again - am thinking the only real solution to this is to restart IIS. Unless anyone anywhere has any ideas? :(

Comment: How do you design the login? According to my understanding, click login and send the account information to the service section for verification. After verification, the user information is stored in the session and sent back. Why is the data not loaded back from the server?

Comment: I don't think the login is working as we'd expect, this issue only ever happens once and always after a publish. The login looks like it worked, however after a login from what I see is the internal UI html form without data. Its very odd, it doesn't happen on my local  build so I cannot replicate this end, it always happens after a publish though.

Comment: We have an admin part in the site so what I'm looking to do after our publish has completed is call something like Session.Abandon() - will attempt this and update if this works..